# JQuery's .load() leads to bad HTML structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I used JQuery's `.load()` function to include another web page inside my current web page, I checked the source code, and I found something similar to this...

```
<html>
   <head>
   <head>
   <body>
       <div>
           <html> //loaded page
              <head>
              </head>
              <body>
              </body>
           </html>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Is there any negative issues when having such a structure? Note that the new page also contains elements such as `<title>` and includes CSS and JavaScript files as well.

Comment: The obvious solution is not to include these tags in the downloaded page. Apart from that, while the HTML is extremely invalid, browsers should have no problem processing and displaying it correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not technically valid HTML, but it shouldn't really cause rendering issues I don't think.

Note that you can specify element selectors in `.load()` so you could potentially just get the  section of the other page that you want, eg:

```
$('div').load('file.html #relevantsection');
```

Comment: Also I noticed that specifying an element (usually inside body) loads that element without any CSS rules applied in the CSS files included in the head of the loaded webpage, means all CSS files should be included in the parent web page.

Comment: Yep, it will load whatever's included in the selector and that's all. Is there a reason you're using .load() for html rather than an AJAX call with proper data or a server side option? It's not generally considered best practice as there are better solutions in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are plenty of issues and especially some important SEO issues...

You either shouldn't be loading entire html docs or use the following example to load specific parts of the target document:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Have a read [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).